# How to debug BlackBerry devices on Mac using the filesystem?

Tags: blackberry, video, java-me, filesystems

How exactly do you go about debugging BlackBerry apps that utilise the (BlackBerry's) filesystem on Mac?

I'm currently recording video and detecting when the video file appears on the file system, however due to the restrictions:

- The BlackBerry file system is auto-mounted when plugged into a Mac
- The app cannot access the filesystem when mounted

These two things have made debugging the app when it uses the filesystem.. impossible! We receive a file system error 1003 which according to the results from google mean it's mounted and you don't have access.

Is there a a simple way to get round this?

*I also receive 63 signing emails from RIM. Woe is me*

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for.. I'd like to debug at some point without having to put dialog boxes to output info at every line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround is a bit cumbersome, but it should work for you.

1. Implement [EventLogger](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EventLogger.html) instance in your application.
2. Log all necessary info via EventLogger
3. Compile and run your app on the **detached** device from your computer.
4. Inspect log (press **CTRL** and hit **LGLG** on the device keyboard). As an additional option - automatically export log to a text file stored in the device filesystem (media card) to review it on your computer.

Comment: I was seconds away to logging out to a flat txt file so this should be better thanks! If this is the way I gotta' do it, then so be it!